# Parsing custom tags using Simple XML Serialization

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I have the below XML :

```
<com.abc.xyz.container>
 <data class="list">
   <com.xyz.abc.VO.fruits>
       <id>28</id>
       <name>
        <![CDATA[ Apple ]]>
       </name>
   </<com.xyz.abc.VO.fruits>

   <com.xyz.abc.VO.fruits>
       <id>29</id>
       <name>
         <![CDATA[ Orange ]]>
       </name>
   </<com.xyz.abc.VO.fruits>
<com.abc.xyz.container>
```

I tried to create class in this manner :

```
@Root(name = "com.abc.xyz.container")
public class Response {

    @Element(required = false)
    private Data list;

    public Data getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(Data list) {
        this.list = list;
    }               
}

public class Data {

    @ElementList(inline = true, name = "com.xyz.abc.VO.fruits", required = false)
    private List<Fruits> fruits;

    public List<Fruits> getfruits() {
        return fruits;
    }

    public void setfruits(List<Fruits> fruits) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }    
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
public class Fruits{

    @Element(required = false)
    private int id;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

But when i try to get the size of the `List<Fruits>` it gives me NullPointerException.

How can i correct my code ? I am using Simple XML Serialization(org.simpleframework.xml.*).

Comment: How does your `Fruits`-Class look like?

Comment: @user2056563 Hey, did you found any solution to this?? I'm stuck in same place here.

Comment: Seeing a couple of Simple XML questions, I wanted to point to **JAXB with annotations** as alternative.